# Flexible Data Label Formatting

Tags: vba, excel, charts, label

I'm hoping to add custom data labels to a stacked bar chart in Excel 2010. Each bar will have a label value pulled from a value in the sheet which is not necessarily equal to the height of the bar itself.

The sheet I'm making is a template and has drop-down selections to change the units of the data. For example: $MM with 1 decimal point, K with 2 decimal points, $ with 0 decimal points, etc... I'm running into an issue formatting the labels to match the data formatting selections. I've tried two approaches:

1. Formatting the data labels themselves using VBA. Partial code below for $K with one decimal:

   ```
   `With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(x).Points(y)`
   ```

   `.DataLabel.Text.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.0,"`

Unfortunately, the labels don't seem to read the commas and divide by one thousand, so I can't accurate display thousands or millions. A value of 1000 in the above code will display as $1,000.0 instead of the desired $1.0.

2. Format the values in the worksheet, and then just read them with VBA. Basically, I use conditional formatting to properly display the values on the sheet, and then read them with `.DataLabel.Text = Cells(r,c)`

Unfortunately, though the data is formatted correctly, the values are unchanged and the labels display with no custom formatting at all.

Is there any reasonable way to achieve my goal? I'm hoping there's a way to either (1) make commas count when changing data label number formats or (2) change the actual values of the data in my sheet based on the formatting drop-down selections (instead of just giving them custom formatting which leaves the value unchanged).

Thank you,
Lance

Answer (score 0):

I think the words "conditional formatting" are your issue here: I've had problems with VBA reading the underlying format of a cell when it's conditionally formatted (admittedly, my issue was with colour, rather than number format, but I expect the reasons for it not working would be the same).

If you adopt your second approach, i.e. relying on the worksheet's format using the chart's "**Linked to source**" option, then on a trigger of when the drop-down option is changed, you could use VBA to **set** the format on the worksheet instead of using conditional formatting - then the chart would pick up whatever format you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
?Format(1000,"$#,##0.0,")
$1.000,0
?Format(1000,"$#,##0,.0")
$1,0
?Format(1234,"$#,##0,.0")
$1,2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the site guidelines about answering questions. Posting code with no explanation about why it helps solve the problem and - in this case - how to use it is discouraged. Your contribution will have more value if you explain how this helps answer the question AND how to use this code snippet. Not everyone will recognize that you're showing information from a VBA Immediate Window...